# How to find the pressed state of linear layout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Here is a scenario.I have a linear layout with a textview and a imageview.Now here I want to change the backgound of another imageview  in the pressed state of the linear layout.I am using the method isPressed.But when I am leaving the linear layout after pressing it,the changes of the pressed state still exists.

Here is my code

```
  lin_featured.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(lin_featured.isPressed())
                {
                    linearmain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imgfooterback.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.discover_h);
                    i =new Intent(FirstPage.this,Featured.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
                else{
                    //imgfooterback.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.footerback);
                    linearmain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imgfooterback.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.footerback);
                }


            }
        });
```

More precisely I just want to find the pressed state of a linear layout programmatically.Please Help.

Comment: use OnTouchListener instead of OnClickListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem like yours. I found the solution myself. Use onTouchListener() instead of onClickListener(). One you have to write a selector for the layout, includes the states pressed and default and then there is the soution. Just set your linearLayout as onTouchListener.

```
public OnTouchListener listener = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //works like view.isPressed()
            //view.setPressed(true);
            linearmain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imgfooterback.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.discover_h);
            i =new Intent(FirstPage.this,Featured.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            view.setPressed(false);
            Rect rect = new Rect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());
            if (rect.contains(view.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), view.getTop() + (int) event.getY())) {
                //works like onclick
                //imgfooterback.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.footerback);
                linearmain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgfooterback.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.footerback);
            }

        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            Rect rect = new Rect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());
            if (!rect.contains(view.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), view.getTop() + (int) event.getY())) {
                //if you move your finger outside of the view, pressed state ends and returns to default state.
                //view.setPressed(false);

            }
        }

        return true;

    }
};
```